# Using canvas tags to represent characters

Tags: canvas, ckeditor

I'd like to use ckeditor to handle "text" that's not actually font-based, but rather, based on 12x40 dot-matrix representations for each letter, where each letter is a canvas tag.

I tried a little experiment where I placed a series of  tags (drawn as squares) in the content area, and moving the text cursor and doing block hilites didn't seem to work.

Does anyone know if this is feasible?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is certainly feasible, there are a lot of things that are feasible. Could you show s your attempts so we can tell you what was wrong?

Comment: Thanks, Kaiido. Actually, it looks like the deal is that in ckeditor, if you place images next to each other, you can't click in between them to create an insertion point. The best you can do (as a user), is to click before/after the entire sequence of images, and then left/right over to get to the insertion spot you want.  Kinda lame for a user. 

I'm thinking that the only option is to somehow intercept the user action and programmatically simulate the user click into the location. Any suggestions?